# Regarding using dll with android app?

Tags: android

I've a "**dll**" file which contains some methods.

I want to import the dll within the android application and use its methods. Is there a way to accomplish this???

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393305/using-dll-library-in-android-application/28393337#28393337

Comment: Here is similer question on stackoverflow....

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908660/how-to-import-dll-to-android-java-project-working-with-eclipse][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908660/how-to-import-dll-to-android-java-project-working-with-eclipse